# How to implement undo swipe and reinsert recently deleted item KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite, undo, snackbar

I have a to do list app and I have created a snackbar that shows up when a user swipes to delete an item. What I want to do is have the undo snackbar reinsert the item that was just deleted.

**Here's my code that handles the swipe to delete and show snackbar**

```
override fun onViewSwiped(position: Int) {

    deleteTask(list[position].ID)
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    updateNotesPositionInDb()

    val snackbar = Snackbar.make((context as Activity).findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "task deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    snackbar.setAction("Undo") {
    }
    snackbar.show()
```

Keep in mind that this code is used in an Adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the deleted item and add it back to the list with undo:

The problem is that you already deleted the task in your database, so I think that you should give that deleteTask some delay and only delete the task if the undo is not clicked during that delay.

```
override fun onViewSwiped(position: Int) {
    val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    deleteTask(list[position].ID)
    val removedItem = list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    updateNotesPositionInDb()

    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        (context as Activity).findViewById(R.id.mainLayout),
        "task deleted",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
    )
    snackbar.setAction("Undo") {
        undoDeleteTask(removedItem.ID)
        list.add(position, removedItem)
        notifyItemInserted(position)
    }
    snackbar.show()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I came up with a solution for the deleteTask() delay as well, so all is good.